# Python : JSON Error: Syntax error, malformed JSON

Tags: python, json, postman

My Python code, which I obtained from POSTMAN, throws an error with the string

**"code":"E101","message":"JSON Error: Syntax error, malformed JSON"}"**

although in POSTMAN, the request was successful and produced the expected JSON result.

below is my python code

```
import requests

url = "APIURL"

payload={'data': '{
    "authenticate":{
        "apikey":"ABCSHF"
    },
    "services":[
        {
            "call":"history/API",
            "identifier":{
                "search":"desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}'}
files=[

]
headers = {

}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Your Python code does not work at all.

Comment: it works , may be because i removed the API key and URL @matszwecja

Comment: Your code creates JSON in JSON. Remove the quotation marks!

Comment: i tried with data=payload too @KlausD.

Comment: The payload is not valid JSON

Comment: But i got the code directly from POSTMAN @Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should get clearness what did you code ;):

`requests` parse a dict to a JSON internally, see [explanation here](https://pynative.com/python-post-json-using-requests-library/)

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

# some JSON string:
json_string = '{ "authenticate":{ "apikey":"ABCSHF" }, "services":[ { "call":"history/API", "identifier":{ "search":"desc" } } ] }'

# parse JSON string to dict:
json_as_dict = json.loads(json_string)

pprint(json_as_dict)
# >> {'authenticate': {'apikey': 'ABCSHF'},
# >>  'services': [{'call': 'history/API', 'identifier': {'search': 'desc'}}]}

incorrect_payload_as_dict = {'data': json.dumps(json_as_dict)}

pprint(incorrect_payload_as_dict)
# >> {'data': '{"authenticate": {"apikey": "ABCSHF"}, "services": [{"call": '
# >>          '"history/API", "identifier": {"search": "desc"}}]}'}

correct_payload_as_dict = {'data': json_as_dict}

pprint(correct_payload_as_dict)
# >> {'data': {'authenticate': {'apikey': 'ABCSHF'},
# >>          'services': [{'call': 'history/API',
# >>                         'identifier': {'search': 'desc'}}]}}
```